# Order by multiple columns SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a list that I should order by multiple columns in SQL.
First I should order the list by Date and after that by OrderCriteria.
I made an SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c135c6/1 with some test data.

The list should be ordered by StatusDate because on the top of the list should be the most recent items. But it should be ordered by OrderCriteria, too, because first it should appear the items with the OrderCriteria 0 and then with the OrderCriteria 1.

In this screenshot it shows what should be the correct order.

[image]

First all the items with the most recent date, but first the OrderCriteria 0 and then where the OrderCriteria is 1.

The correct order should be:I have added to the SQL Fiddle.
I have tried to Order By the StatusDate, which orders correctly the items, but does not takes in account the OrderCriteria. It orders only by Date.
I have tried to order by

```
ORDER BY  StatusDate DESC, OrderCriteria asc
```

without OrderCriteria. But I still didn't get the desired result. 
Can you please advise how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to want the *date* in the `StatusDate` to have precedence.  Then within the date, use `OrderCriteria` and the time component.

So:

```
ORDER BY DATE(StatusDate) DESC, OrderCriteria asc, StatusDate DESC
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c135c6/7) is the SQL Fiddle.

Extracting the date from a date/time varies by database.  Your SQL Fiddle is MySQL, so I have used the syntax for that database.

In SQL Server, this would be:

```
ORDER BY CONVERT(DATE, StatusDate) DESC, OrderCriteria asc, StatusDate DESC
```

Comment: Thanks. Exactly this is what I need. I forgot to mention that I'm using MSSQL Server where I get error 'DATE' is not a recognized built-in function name. Do you know how to use it properly in MSSQL Server?I've tried with CONVERT(date,GETDATE()), but it is not ok.

Answer (score 0):

[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c135c/3)

In ms sql server, you can use this :

```
Select * from test 
ORDER BY cast(StatusDate as date) DESC, OrderCriteria asc, StatusDate DESC
```